# Complex integral - should we use contour integration or substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

My question is: how is the following integral  calculated:
$$\int_{0 }^{\infty}  e^{x(1+it)} dx $$

Here, $i$ is imaginary unit, and $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is some parameter. My questions are:

1. Can we use complex substitution e.g. $ u= x(1- it ) $ and why? If we can do it, how do we determine limits of integral?
2. If we cannot use complex substitution, how do we determine contour for integration? I know how Residuum theorem is applied, but I don't know which contour to take and also.
3. I am confused when it is allowed to use substitution and when to use contour integration.

Also, I would be very grateful if someone can recommend any book related to Complex integration (with lot of exercises and explanations, for beginners). Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I recall correctly complex-valued substitutions can be pretty dodgy, however here I think that you could use it as a tool to find an antiderivative for your integrand and then use the Fundamental Theorem of Contour Integration

Comment: The integral does not exist; you cannot evaluate it by any method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to use substitution or contour inegration.
Since you cannot show that the integral converges - using any contour that goes to infinity (say along the imaginary axis) will not help the case.
You can simply do the real and imaginary part of the indefinite  integral:
$$
\int e^x\cos tx-i\int e^x\sin tx
$$
Each of this integrals can be done by integrating by parts twice and moving the resulting integral to the left. We consider:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}[ I(x)] -I(0)=I(\infty)-I(0)
$$
where $I(0)$ is finite but
$$
I(\infty)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{1+t^2}\bigg[\sin tx +\cos tx-i(t\sin tx-\cos  tx)\bigg]
$$
which diverges since both the real and imaginary parts oscillate between increasingly large numbers.